# Is adding "in the (professional league)" awkward here?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I am not sure if this is grammatically correct, I think it's correct, but it's weird and doesn't sound super idiomatic.

Let's take a look at this example:

> We should replace all the old goaltenders in the NHL with younger less
>   experienced goaltenders from the AHL to increase the number of goals.

Does "in the NHL" after goaltenders sound weird and unidiomatic? How would you rephrase it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The sentence is fine but can be condensed if desired

You can condense the wording like this:

> We should replace all the old NHL goaltenders with younger, less experienced AHL goaltenders to increase the number of goals.

This is a matter of style, however, not grammar. As it is, the sentence doesn't sound "odd." In fact, by writing it out as you have, the hockey league initials are emphasized at little more, highlighting the fact that you're talking about goaltenders from two different leagues.